# Can I remove this notification/add from google chrome start page?

Tags: google-chrome

I am getting some advertisement-like notifications whenever I start Google Chrome. There is a cross button which makes it disappear, but it reappears after some time. I have shown it in the picture.

[image]

I have two questions

1. Do this notification/add has a particular name? I tried to google search regarding how to remove it, but couldn't find anything.
2. Is there a way to **permanently** disable this?

Comment: not sure if this is an acceptable solution to you but you could change the startpage to google.com instead of this New Tab Page

Comment: Did you try AdBlock or anything similar?

Comment: @Destroy666 I have AdBlock Plus installed. It didn't affect this notification.

Comment: @Gantendo Can I somehow build a similar-looking start page with a search box and a few pinned URLs?

Comment: @AbhikBose You could use abhik.net/startpage.html